# inflation error in rivz

Tags: slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I trying to run Stage together with move_base and either gmapping or map_server+amcl but i realized that inflation message is not reflected on rviz although the message is received as shown in these video: [Gmapping](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40fPqtjxOzI) and [Map_server](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnuXxNZmzBg).

If I run the program in actual environment (replaced Stage with laser driver and p2os_driver), the inflated appeared with the Map_server combination but not in Gmapping.

How should i handle this problem? Thanks for the assistance

With regards,

Zhiping

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9485/inflation-error-in-rivz/) by [zhiping](https://answers.ros.org/users/131/zhiping/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2011-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Zhiping,

From the videos you posted it looks like the navigation stack isn't receiving laser data from stage correctly. No obstacles, raw or inflated, are showing up in the costmap. Is navigation giving you any errors? Are you sure that you've configured navigation to run with the correct topic name for the laser? Is there anything notably different in the topics provided by the p2os driver versus stage that would prevent the same configuration files from working in both scenarios?

Hope all is well,

Eitan

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zhiping](https://answers.ros.org/users/131/zhiping/) on 2011-03-22**:
Thanks for the tip, Eitan. Apparently, the Stage provide the tf between /base_link to /base_laser_link instead of base_link to /base_laser. To solve this problem, i just need to change the laser_frame in costmap_common_param.yaml